# How to set audio endpoint volume range?

Tags: windows, audio

How can I change the volume range of an audio endpoint programatically?
There is a Windows API for getting it `IAudioEndpointVolume::GetVolumeRange` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nf-endpointvolume-iaudioendpointvolume-getvolumerange), but not for setting it.

Registry tweaking would be OK for me. The properties reside at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio`, but I can't figure out where and how the volume range is stored.

Background: some drivers report wrong values that I want to correct.
C++, Java or Python solutions are ok for me.

Comment: c++ solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48838523/4603670

Comment: This is for changing the volume (e.g. set it to 50 %), but I need to change the range, i.e. the values for the minimum and maximum that determine how loud a certain percentage is. A driver bug sometimes causes the maximum and minimum set to the same value.