# ISimpleAudioVolume::SetMasterVolume for specific application

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, mixer

According this code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48838523/3478155
the overall sound is adjusted.
But I need to adjust the sound of a specific application.
Also, i need to display a list of applications that appear when the volume mixer is activated (by clicking on it with the mouse, as an example).

Answer (score 1):

[ISimpleAudioVolume::SetMasterVolume method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-isimpleaudiovolume-setmastervolume) sets the master volume level for the audio session. In my opinion, you couldn't use the method for specific application.

I suggest you could try to use  [ISimpleAudioVolume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nn-audioclient-isimpleaudiovolume) and [IAudioSessionEvents interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessionevents). For more details you can refer to the Doc: [Volume Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/volume-controls)

When you use an app to play a sound, the app will appear in the Volume Mixer.

Comment: Ya, thanks. In all SO nobody can't post full code for this. Why...

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the offical sample:https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/MFPlayer2/AudioSessionVolume.cpp